# SQL query to compare between 2 reports timestamp and show increase/decrease trend

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using below query to get `Input_MB` and `Output_MB` for current timestamp. 
However i need to compare with previous 1 hour data  how the input and out put value was there for the same rows. Based on that i need to put increase/decrease trend.

Query i used for getting 9:30 and 10:30 report is:

```
SELECT
  A.last_updated,
  B.SERVER AS Server,
  D.STREAM_NAME AS Stream,
  A.INPUT AS Input,
  A.OUTPUT AS Output
FROM table1 A,
     table2 B,
     table3 C,
     table4 D
WHERE A.ALARM_BACKLOG = '1'
AND C.MONIT_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
AND A.NODE_MAN_ID = B.NODE_MAN_ID
AND A.NODE_ID = C.NODE_ID
AND B.STR_ID = D.STR_ID
AND B.NODE_MAN_ID = C.NODE_MAN_ID
ORDER BY NM.HOST_SERVER_NAME, S.STREAM_NAME DESC
```

Suppose 9:30 AM report is:

```
Last_updated    Server  stream  input   output
9:30 AM A   1   80  0
9:30 AM EFH 7   8   20
9:30 AM D   5   60  0
9:30 AM E   8   25  100
```

and 10:30 AM report supposed to be:

```
Last_updated    Server  stream  input   output
10:30 AM    A   1   40  0
10:30 AM    C   7   0   8
10:30 AM    D   5   72  0
10:30 AM    B   3   0   0
10:30 AM    E   8   25  115
```

However i want 10:30 report should come as below.

```
Last_updated    Server  stream  input   "Input 
Trend"  output  "Output
 Trend"
10:30 AM    A   1   40  50%-Down    0   No change
10:30 AM    C   7   0   New 8   New
10:30 AM    D   5   72  20%- Up 0   New
10:30 AM    B   3   0   New 0   New
10:30 AM    E   8   25  No change   15%-Up  New
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this (i wrote without test)

```
  Select A.last_updated, A.SERVER, B.Stream,A.INPUT,
Case 
    When B.INPUT is Null Then 'New'
    When A.INPUT=B.INPUT Then 'No change'
    When A.INPUT<B.INPUT Then Cast((B.INPUT-A.INPUT)/B.INPUT*100 as Varchar(10))+'%-Down'
    When A.INPUT>B.INPUT Then Cast((A.INPUT-B.INPUT)/B.INPUT*100 as Varchar(10))+'%-Up'
End INPUT_TREND,
A.OUTPUT,
Case 
    When B.OUTPUT is Null Then 'New'
    When A.OUTPUT=B.OUTPUT Then 'No change'
    When A.OUTPUT<B.OUTPUT Then Cast((B.OUTPUT-A.OUTPUT)/B.OUTPUT*100 as Varchar(10))+'%-Down'
    When A.OUTPUT>B.OUTPUT Then Cast((A.OUTPUT-B.OUTPUT)/B.OUTPUT*100 as Varchar(10))+'%-Up'
End INPUT_TREND

From 
(
 Select A.last_updated, B.SERVER, D.STREAM_NAME as Stream, A.INPUT, A.OUTPUT ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.last_updated Desc) Row_id
 From table1 A
 Join table2 B on A.NODE_MAN_ID = B.NODE_MAN_ID
 Join table3 C on A.NODE_ID = C.NODE_ID and  B.NODE_MAN_ID= C.NODE_MAN_ID 
 Join table4 D on B.STR_ID = D.STR_ID
 Where A.ALARM_BACKLOG = '1' and C.MONIT_STATUS = 'ACTIVE') A
Left join 
(
 Select A.last_updated, B.SERVER, D.STREAM_NAME as Stream, A.INPUT, A.OUTPUT,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY A.last_updated Desc) Row_id 
 From table1 A
 Join table2 B on A.NODE_MAN_ID = B.NODE_MAN_ID
 Join table3 C on A.NODE_ID = C.NODE_ID and  B.NODE_MAN_ID= C.NODE_MAN_ID 
 Join table4 D on B.STR_ID = D.STR_ID
 Where A.ALARM_BACKLOG = '1' and C.MONIT_STATUS = 'ACTIVE') B on B.Row_id=A.Row_id+1 and A.SERVER=B.SERVER and A.Stream=B.Stream
Where A.last_updated='10:30 AM'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. INPUT is there only in one table that is table1. Any particular reason you have added..A.INPUT=B.INPUT

Comment: A and B are aliases for subquerys

Comment: ORA-00904: "A"."ROW_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 33 Column: 84

Comment: i have changed row_id to rowid and now i am getting ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 19 Column: 61

Comment: something is wrong in this syntax...    Select a.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.last_updated DESC) rowid

Comment: Ok it's, Oracle. I will answer you soon

Comment: I have used your new code.. i am getting below errors now..    ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Are subquerys in the from clause executing fine ?

Comment: sorry for replying late... subqueries are working fine....but in main select block it showing error

Comment: Instead of + i tried with || operator it is working fine...I  am just checking for timestamp which should be in second block i guess..

Comment: Execly, use II Instead of + .I forgot change this.